# How to tell what is causing a "missing or insufficient permissions" error in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm working on a social media application where users can create posts and post them on a public feed.

Users are able to block other users.

Blocked users cannot see the posts of the blocker, and the blocker cannot see the posts of the blockee.

I'd like this to be handled server-side so it's a lot harder for blocked users to query for posts they are not supposed to see. It's also extremely convenient for client-side code so I don't need to check if a post is viewable for every post.

I use these security rules for this:

```
function userIsAllowedToSeePost(userUid, postUid, postAuthorUid) {
        return (!exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(postAuthorUid)/blockedUsers/$(userUid)) &&
             !exists(/database/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(userUid)/blockedUsers/$(postAuthorUid)));
    }


match /posts/{postId} {
      allow create: ... # not relevant
      allow read: if userIsAllowedToSeePost(request.auth.uid, postId, resource.data.userUid);
      allow delete, update: if false;
```

With these rules, it's normal that a user will query for a specific post using a post id and get the "Missing or insufficient permissions" error.

The issue is that I don't know how to differentiate between the "blocked user" error and other errors that could happen for any other reason.

I'm wondering if this is a good approach for this or if I should try something else?

I would like to avoid a client-side check or a Firebase Function to do the querying for me to see if the user is blocked by the post author, although this doesn't seem possible.

I personally like this approach... I just wish I had a way to differentiate between an intended error and an unintentional one.

I guess to the client, no matter the case, if a post is not viewable that should be enough to figure out what to do in most cases. However, for debugging, it'd be very useful to know the reason a post is not viewable.

Comment: I wrote some considerations below. Not a real answer, but it was too long to post in a comment. In general, we'd need to see how you want to query the data - as I'm having a hard time thinking up a query that meets the conditions of the rules you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach sounds good to me, but there's no way in the client to determine which part of the security rules rejected the write. That is intentional, as any such information is knowledge that a malicious user can use in further attacks.

With Firebase security rules the logic in your code should be that you only request data that you have access to.

So in this use-case you should have a query that only requests posts that are from users that haven't blocked the current user. It'll be tricky to do that in the same way as your security now checks (with a `get()` of another document) as Firestore queries can only filter on data in the documents that they actually retrieve.

Comment: Got it. My querying mechanism is pretty simple. All users have a personal post feed that you can query given a user uid. The personal post feed only stores the post uid, author uid and the creation date so I can easily query posts by time. Then I use the post uids to query the posts collection you see above that has the rules. I'm guessing I just need to check for every post I look up, check if the user is blocked by the post author. It's something that I wanted to avoid, but I guess its necessary even with security rules.